# Does Sylvanas' "Possession" work on boss?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

Sylvanas' "Possession" on level 10:

> Force an enemy Minion to fight for you. It gains 30% Attack Damage and Health. Cooldown increased to 20 seconds when used on Catapults.

... and on level 20 "Dark Lady's Call":

> Increases the Attack Damage and Health bonus to 30% and allows Possession of enemy Mercenaries with a 20 second cooldown.

... seems not that useful unless it works on boss. Does it?

Comment: Not that useful?? It is like 2 charges of bribe (kill enemy+get ally in one go), but 3 times per minute instead of 3 times per game.

Comment: "Force an enemy Minion to fight for you." Bosses are not minions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not affect bosses. See also [this](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/735939-heroes-of-the-storm/71714435) thread on gamefaqs or [this](http://us.battle.net/heroes/en/forum/topic/16774527342#5) reaction on battle.net:

> > Also with it's position, I wouldn't be surprised if it worked on bosses.
>
> It's already confirmed that it can't touch bosses.

(although I cannot find that confirmation)

Comment: I would argue that the confirmation is built into the description of the ability itself. It goes out of its way to specify that it works against Minions at level 10 and extends to Mercenaries at level 20. Considering that hovering over a camp displays if it belongs to Mercenaries or a Boss, it stands to reason that if they had intended for the ability to work with bosses they would have added that wording into the description of the ability.

Comment: Though the ping audible for when you want to capture a boss says "mercenary camp", this spell as well as "Bribe" and "Recruitment" talents don't work on bosses.